# TypeError: Backbone.$(...).on is not a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Ploblem with Backbone.Router.

I have navigation

My code:

```
        <div id="menu"> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#!/">Start</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!/success">Success</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!/error">Error</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  

     <script>
```

```
    $(function () {
    var Control = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "": "start", 
            "!/": "start", 
            "!/success": "success", 
            "!/error": "error" 
        },

        start: function () {
           console.log('start')
        },

        success: function () {
    console.log('success');
        },

        error: function () {
    console.log('error')
         //   $(".block").hide();
         //   $("#error").show();
        }
    });

var controllers = new Control(); 

Backbone.history.start();   


});
```

**Error:**

> TypeError: Backbone.$(...).on is not a function
>
> Backbone.$(window).on('hashchange', this.checkUrl);

Comment: I created fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fad8U/58/ but error cannot be reproduced. Are you sure, you use latest versions of libraries?

Comment: Are you using a version of jQuery before 1.7 perhaps? [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) was added to jQuery in version 1.7.

Comment: I used jquery 1.6.Thanks.